# IOServiceAddMatchingNotification issue

Tags: c++, c, xcode, callback, firewire

void functions::start()
    {

```
io_iterator_t enumerator;

...some code...

result = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(
            mNotifyPort,
                                        kIOMatchedNotification,
                                        IOServiceMatching( "IOFireWireLocalNode" ),
                                        serviceMatchingCallback, 
                                        (void *)0x1234,
                                        &enumerator  );    <=====
}
```

> functions.cpp:83: error: argument of
>   type 'void (functions::)(void*,
>   io_iterator_t)' does not match 'void
>   (*)(void*, io_iterator_t)'

---

does anyone know what this error mean? I am calling `start()` from `main()` through an object of functions ( eg, `f->start();` )

i am using xcode and it highlights the line where the arrow points.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `serviceMatchingCallback`? Judging by the error, it seems to be a member function. You can't pass a member function as a callback in this manner. See [this recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707575/c-static-function-wrapper-that-routes-to-member-function/1707619#1707619) on calling a class member function from a callback.