# Register callback from a manager class to a worker class without the worker having to have a reference to the manager when executing the callback

Tags: c++, callback

I'm having some troubles getting the design which I planned into C++ code.

I have a `Manager` class, which will create some instances of another class `SomeClass`. These instances will do some work in seperate threads. One of these instances will be designated as `theOne` and will notify the manager in some way when it is done performing its task. From that notification, the manager should get the results (if available) of all other instances with some function `getData()`.

I thought I can realize this via a callback style notification. In the sense that the manager registers its `getData()` function in the instanciated class, which is the `theOne`, as a callback. If `theOne` has finished its job, it will just call its `isDone()` member, which executes the registered callback inside the manager. However doing it this way `SomeClass` always needs to have a reference to the `Manager` instance, which I actually don't want, because I only want the manager to know of `SomeClass` (instances) and not the other way around.

Is there a way I can tackle this problem? Or is my design just not suited for that? If it is not, is there another more suitable design with which I can realize this.

Here is the code I got (which is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537131/how-to-pass-a-method-as-callback-to-another-class)). The calls I'm doing in `main()` will of course later be called in the respective class members.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Manager {
    public:
    void getData(int)
    {
        std::cout << "Got it!";
    }
};

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() : callback() { }
    typedef std::function<void(Manager*, int)> Callback;

    void registerCallback(const Callback& c)
    {
        callback = c;
    }

    void isDone(Manager* p)
    {
        callback(p, 42);
    }
private:
    Callback callback;
};

int main()
{
    // This should be called in the manager class, which will instanciate its
    // SomeClass workers. This works fine.
    SomeClass sc;
    sc.registerCallback(&Manager::getData);

    // This should be called in SomeClass. 
    // The manager object is needed for the execution of the callback, which I
    // want to omit.
    Manager cb;
    sc.isDone(&cb);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the callback generic, and pass a function object that captures a pointer to the `Manager`:

```
// in SomeClass
typedef std::function<void(int)> Callback;
Callback callback;
```

and instantiate as needed. For example, in manager:

```
// in Manager
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto f1 = std::bind(&Manager::getData, this, _1);
auto f2 = [this](int i) { getData(i); }
SomeClass sc;
sc.registerCallback(f1);
sc.registerCallback(f2);
```

or anywhere else:

```
void foo(int i) { std::cout << "foo called with i = " << i << "\n"; }

SomeClass sc;
sc.registerCallback(foo);
```