# How to use non-static member function as pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, live555

I'm writing RTSP client and after creating it with

```
class RtspClientManager
{
private:
    rtsp_client;
    void continueAfterDescribe(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString);
}

...

rtsp_client = RTSPClient::createNew(*env, szUrl);
```

i'm sending describe command:

```
rtsp_client->sendDescribeCommand(continueAfterDescribe);
```

I would like to have a `continueAfterDescribe` as `RtspClientManager::continueAfterDescribe` instance member and have access to all the members.

Of course `continueAfterDescribe` could be  a static member function but then I would only have access to static members. How to pass a pointer to a non-static member function and have access to all instance members within RtspClientManager??

RTSPClient method sendDescribeCommand has such signature:

```
unsigned RTSPClient::sendDescribeCommand(responseHandler* responseHandler);

typedef void (responseHandler)(RTSPClient* rtspClient,
             int resultCode, char* resultString);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a qualified non-static member function as a function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499153/passing-a-qualified-non-static-member-function-as-a-function-pointer)

Comment: Is `RTSPClient` your class? or library class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to use `static` function. But in your situation you can pass a `RtspClientManager` object as a parameter to the function and then use other methods/members of that object. Also your declarations are not correct, they should be like this:

```
typedef void (*responseHandler)(RTSPClient* rtspClient,
         int resultCode, char* resultString);

unsigned RTSPClient::sendDescribeCommand(responseHandler responseHandler);
```